# Scala: delay code bloc execution or cancel it

Tags: scala, scheduled-tasks, delay

I'm pretty new to Scala and have a background in Java.

The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to execute a function after 5 minutes. And also be able to cancel this at any time.

In java I would basically use [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), and set it to 5 min. If I would like to cancel, I just call `cancel` method. The nice thing is, I can use that Java class in Scala. But as I'm still learning Scala, I'm just wondering if I'm missing any better way of accomplishing that in a better way. I ran into `Future` and `Await.result` Scala classes, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if you are using some kind of a framework, it would provide its own abstraction to deal with scheduled tasks. Finagle has a `Timer` class, based on netty's `HashedWheelTimer` for example, Akka has `Scheduler`, etc.
(It is a good idea to use the same scheduling framework throughout the entire application, because that allows for a more efficient use of resources).

If you are just writing "vanilla" scala code without any framework, there is nothing wrong with just using `TimerTask` directly or, perhaps, make a little wrapper around it, so that it is not as awkward to use in scala code:

```
class FutureTask[T](f: => Future[T]) extends TimerTask {  
  val promise = Promise[T]()
  def run(): Unit = promise.completeWith(f)
  override def cancel() = {
     val result = super.cancel
     if(result) promise.complete(Failure(new CancellationException))
     result
  }
}

object FutureTask {
   implicit def toFuture[T](task: FutureTask[T]) = task.promise.future

   def scheduleFlat[T](when: Duration)(f: => Future[T])(implicit timer: Timer = defaultTimer): FutureTask[T] = {
     val task = new FutureTask(f)
     timer.schedule(task, when.toMillis)
     task          
   }

   def schedule[T](when: Duration)(f: => T)(implicit timer: Timer = defaultTimer, ctx: ExecutionContext): FutureTask[T] = 
     scheduleFlat(when)(Future(f))(timer)

   val defaultTimer = new java.util.Timer(true)
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
val someTask = FutureTask
  .schedule(5 seconds) { println("Hello!") }
someTask.onComplete { result => println("Completed with " + result) }
someTask.cancel
Await.result(someTask, 2 seconds)
```

etc.

Comment: Actually what you said is interesting: "(It is a good idea to use the same scheduling framework throughout the entire application, because that allows for a more efficient use of resources)"
We're actually Akka for managing our event based app, and this timeout implementation that I have to do will take place in this environment, I just ran into something interesting from Akka: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html
Seems like I'm all set ;)

Comment: What I say is _always_ interesting

Answer (score 2):

The `Future` in the scala library is not cancellable. What you'd have to do would be to implement some sort of a condition and make sure you "thing" only runs as long as that condition is true.

You might want to look at `monix.Task`, which is cancellable: https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html

From their docs:

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.CancelableFuture
import concurrent.duration._

val task = Task(1 + 1).delayExecution(1.second)

val result: CancelableFuture[Int] =
  task.runAsync

// If we change our mind
result.cancel()
```

Comment: It sounds like it would do the job, I'll go implement some tests to check it out ;)